# rake db:seed throwing attrubute not found error when trying to populate foreign key field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am trying to set up a relationship in my application so that:

```
a broadcast has 0..1 post and 0..1 jobs
```

i have looked into `belongs_to` and `has_one` and i have tried to implement these, i have other examples of doing so in my application which are working so i cant figure out why this is not.

here are my `posts` and `jobs` tables

```
class CreateJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :jobs do |t|
      t.text :title, null: :no #Must have a title
      t.string :content, default: 'No content specified'
      t.references :broadcast, null: :no, index: true  # Must have been broadcast
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.text :title, null: :no #Must have a title
      t.string :content, default: 'No content specified'
      t.references :broadcast, null: :no, index: true  # Must have been broadcast
      t.timestamps  # Created at will double up as post date
    end
  end
end
```

here are my `broadcast.rb`, `job.rb`, `post.rb` definitions for the relationship

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  #A post makes no sense without a title and content, they must exits.
  validates_presence_of :title, :content

  belongs_to :broadcast
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

  #A job makes no sense without a title and content, they must exits.
  validates_presence_of :title, :content

  belongs_to :broadcast
end

class Broadcast < ActiveRecord::Base

  # The only restriction is that broadcasts must have some data to
  # be valid and an associated broadcaster (user_id)
  validates_presence_of :content, :title

  # 0..1 relationship between job/post and broadcast
  has_one :post
  has_one :job
end
```

This is the `schema.rb` after `db:migrate`

```
create_table "broadcasts", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.boolean  "jobs",       default: false
    t.boolean  "general",    default: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

add_index "jobs", ["broadcast_id"], name: "index_jobs_on_broadcast_id"

  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "title"
    t.string   "content",      default: "No content specified"
    t.integer  "broadcast_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "posts", ["broadcast_id"], name: "index_posts_on_broadcast_id"

  create_table "user_details", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "login",            limit: 40
    t.string  "salt",             limit: 40
    t.string  "crypted_password", limit: 40
    t.integer "user_id"
  end
```

and this is the `seeds.rb` file

```
broadcast = Broadcast.create!(title: 'seed title 1 Broadcast', content: 'seeded Broadcast', jobs: true, general: true,
                              user: user)

 Post.create!(title: 'seed title 1', content: "#{broadcast.content}", broadcast: broadcast)

 broadcast2 = Broadcast.create!(title: 'seed title 2 Broadcast', content: 'Another seeded broadcast', general: true,
                              user: user)

 broadcast3 = Broadcast.create!(title: 'seed title 3 Broadcast', content: 'Another seeded broadcast', jobs: true,
                                                           user: user)

 Post.create!(title: 'seed title 2', content: "#{broadcast2.content}", broadcast: broadcast2)

 Job.create!(title: 'seed title 1 job', content: "#{broadcast.content}", broadcast: broadcast2)
 Job.create!(title: 'seed title 2 job', content: "#{broadcast2.content}", broadcast: broadcast3)
```

This is the error message thrown from `rake db:seed`

I have checked the database in a SQL explorer and the tables do exist, i am not sure why this error persists.

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: broadcast
```

on this line:

```
 Post.create!(title: 'seed title 1', content: "#{broadcast.content}", broadcast: broadcast)
```

if you need more code, just ask me. No doubt i am missing something obvious, but doing something like this worked in my other projects.

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: Your code should work..I don't know why association not taking the `broadcast` object the way you are giving. It should work.

Comment: Where is your `broadcast` migration.. Show that.

Comment: turn outs my computer was at fault, i reset my machine and it now works.

Comment: Good .. good!!..........